# Generate switch cases in php from an array?

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement

Is it possible to generate the cases for a switch in php using an array? Something like:

```
$x=array(
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'bar',
    2 => 'foobar'
);

$y='foobar'

switch($y) {
    foreach($x as $i) {
        case $i:
            print 'Variable $y tripped switch: '.$i.'<br>';
            break;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to pull the case values from a database and loop through them with a while() loop.

Comment: No. What do you want to use this for? Why do you think you need a switch/case?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, `switch` is overcomplicating it. What you want is not possible, and for good reason - that code could be written as simply `foreach($x as $i) { if ($i == $y) { print 'Variable $y tripped switch: '.$i.'<br>'; } }` (assuming you got your `$x`s and your `$i`s confused in that code sample)

Comment: I didn't really need it, it was just something I wound up tinkering with out of speculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A switch is a switch but you can use the array-key to pick the right value. Basically in your array you would make key and value is the same and then you can use if function like so:

```
if ($array[$key]) ....
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe what you are looking for is something along the line of this

```
foreach ($x as $i) {
    switch($i){
        case $y:
            print 'Variable $x tripped switch: '.$i.'<br>';
            break;
    }
}
```